# Parser XML to custom format

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xmlstreamreader

I have following input:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlrest.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://somepage.net/sk/caf/ws">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <ws:messageIdHeader>
         <ws:messageId>1234545</ws:messageId>
      </ws:messageIdHeader>
      <ws:messageIdHeader>
         <ws:messageId>9999999</ws:messageId>
      </ws:messageIdHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:getClientRequest>
         <ws:caid>000899</ws:caid>
      </ws:getClientRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Output has to be following in this case:

```
| Envelope.Header.messageIdHeader.0.messageId | 1234545 |
| Envelope.Header.messageIdHeader.1.messageId | 9999999 |
| Envelope.Body.getClientRequest.caid         | 0008997 |
```

I have tried some operations with DOM, but still with no required result.
Problem is when methods getNextSiblings.getNodeName()/getPreviousSiblings.getNodeName() method are invoked. They doesn't return name of the tag, but some bullshit. And I can't figure out which element has siblings or not. Simple said, I need to index elements, which has siblings, but I don't know how to do it.
Have you please some suggestions ? :)

That's code what I used, but without required result:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("/Some/path/tothis.xml");
        XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        String expression = "//*[not(*)]";

        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory =
                DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(file);
        document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList)
                xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.println("| "+ new Parser2().getNodePath(nodeList.item(i)) +" | " + nodeList.item(i).getTextContent() + " |");
        }
    }

    public String getNodePath(Node node) {
        if(node == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Node cannot be null");
        }
        StringBuilder pathBuilder = new StringBuilder(".");
        String [] lastNode = node.getNodeName().split(":");
        pathBuilder.append(lastNode[1]);

        Node currentNode = node;

        if(currentNode.getNodeType() != Node.DOCUMENT_NODE) {
            while (currentNode.getParentNode() != null) {
                currentNode = currentNode.getParentNode();

                if(currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.DOCUMENT_NODE) {
                    break;
                } else if(getIndexOfArrayNode(currentNode) != null) {
                    String [] nodeName = currentNode.getNodeName().split(":");
                    pathBuilder.insert(0, nodeName[1] +  getIndexOfArrayNode(currentNode).toString() +".");
                } else {
                    String [] nodeName = currentNode.getNodeName().split(":");
                    pathBuilder.insert(0, nodeName[1] +"." );
                }
            }
        }

        return pathBuilder.toString();
    }

    private boolean isArrayNode(Node node) {
        if (node.getNextSibling() == null && node.getPreviousSibling() == null) {
            // Node has no siblings
            return false;
        } else {
            // Check if node siblings are of the same name. If so, then we are inside an array.
            return (node.getNextSibling() != null && node.getNextSibling().getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase(node.getNodeName()))
                    || (node.getPreviousSibling() != null && node.getPreviousSibling().getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase(node.getNodeName()));
        }
    }

    private Integer getIndexOfArrayNode(Node node) {
        if(isArrayNode(node)) {
            int leftCount = 0;

            Node currentNode = node.getNextSibling();

            while(currentNode != null) {
                leftCount++;
                currentNode = currentNode.getPreviousSibling();
            }
            return leftCount;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: posted, thx, I mean that is not possible only using XMLStreamReader, but I need cast every element to Node, but there is problem :/

Comment: code what I used doesn't return indexes of elements and it returns every event, but need only path where is value , thx

Comment: Most people use XSLT for transforming XML to text. It can be fiddly, but Java can be fiddly as well (as you are finding out). If you prefer to stick with a Java solution, I would advise using a DOM rather than XMLStreamReader. That way, you will have the entire XML tree in memory and it will be easy to pick up the index from the parent node.